# How to enable password managers autofill feature for flutter apps?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, autofill

we're currently developing a [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) app ([Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) language).

There is a Login Screen with two [TextField](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)'s.

The password field has

```
obscureText: true,
```

as [property](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/obscureText.html), which hides any input.

**Password Manager**

More and more people are using password manager like 1password.
How can we enable this feature in flutter?

Like this:

[image: Example in other App]

Currently the popup doesn't show. Nothing found on the official docs, maybe there is a google documentation about it in general?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Check out the [Autofill framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill). Also, you can follow [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13015) for native support.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like there is a bigger issue related to that.. Will wait until a new buildroot was created..

Comment: This question is duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633695/flutter-password-autofill/61939545#61939545

Answer (score 2):

Check out the **[platform_inputs](https://pub.dev/packages/platform_inputs)** package:
https://pub.dev/packages/platform_inputs

Their code sample seems to match your problem, it shows how when a textfield's `textContentType` is set to `TextContentType.password` with this package it will show the native password message.

Comment: package has been DISCONTINUED.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `TextField`s with a `AutofillGroup` widget, then mark your `TextField`s with appropriate `AutofillHint`s as in the example code below. Then Google's [Autofill](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill) framework will show suggestions for filling both email and password automatically.

```
            return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                child: AutofillGroup(
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        TextField(
                          autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
                          hintText: "Email address",
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          hintText: "Password",
                          autofillHints: [AutofillHints.password, AutofillHints.newPassword],
                        ),
                       ]
              )));
```

The screenshot below shows the result:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! It works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problem in a flutter web app.

Turns out some modern browsers ([chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=649162) [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1629226)) do not autofill saved passwords inside a `shadow-root`.

The only workaround I've found so far is to  force your app to not use `shadow-root` by editing `embedder.dart`<sup>1</sup> at `_createHostNode` function to not use `shadow-root`

<sup>1</sup> mine was found at: `~/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/embedder.dart`

my build server - using `cirrusci/flutter` docker image had it at `/sdks/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/embedder.dart`